# this two methods are defined in class constructor why it shows error

Tags: flutter

[image]

final Function manageFavorite;
final Function isFavorite;

TripsDetail(this.manageFavorite, this.isFavorite);

Comment: Don't paste code or errors as images. Paste as text and use the formatting options to make it easier to read.

Comment: error: The method 'manageFavorite' isn't defined for the type '_TripsDetailState'. (undefined_method at [toursim_guide] lib\screens\Trips_detail.dart:124)

Comment: Don't put images of code. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Be careful about how to post a question in StackOverflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access member variables defined in the widget class from the state class, you have to prepend the variable with `widget`. E.g. `widget.foo` if you have a variable called `foo`.

Comment: it shows error when i run the project